# Encode JSON objects in JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest

I'm trying to encode 2 name/value pairs in a JSON object within a JSON array. At the moment I am able to encode the name/value pairs but each one goes in as a separate object within the array.

Here is my code:

```
    if ($tag == "getLatLng")
    {
        $lineNumber = $_GET['lineNumber'];
        $coordinates = $db->getCoOrds($lineNumber);

        if ($coordinates != false)
        {
            //Get data and set success = 1
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response['coordinates'] = array();

            $arrayLength = count($coordinates);

            foreach ($coordinates as $value)
            //for ($i=0; $i<$arrayLength+1; $i++)
            {
                //echo $i;
            $response["coordinates"][]['latitude'] = $value[0];
            $response["coordinates"][]['longitude'] = $value[1];
            //$response["coordinates"][]['longitude'] = $coordinates[$i];
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

This is a sample output:

```
    {"success":1,"error":0,"coordinates":[{"latitude":"00.000000"},{"longitude":"-00.000000"},{"latitude":"00.000000"},{"longitude":"-00.000000"},{"latitude":"00.000000"},{"longitude":"-00.000000"}]}
```

But I need this:

```
    {"success":1,"error":0,"coordinates":[{"latitude":"00.000000","longitude":"-00.000000"},{"latitude":"00.000000","longitude":"-00.000000"},{"latitude":"00.000000","longitude":"-00.000000"}]}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $i=0;
foreach ($coordinates as $value)
        //for ($i=0; $i<$arrayLength+1; $i++)
        {

        $response["coordinates"][$i]['latitude'] = $value[0];
        $response["coordinates"][$i]['longitude'] = $value[1];
        $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, works perfect. Can you explain to me what this does please?

Comment: Sure. When you use 

    $response["coordinates"][]['latitude'] 

an incremented value is assigned to the empty key, so if you repeat it, every time it will get an incremented value and makes it as 
    $response["coordinates"][0]['latitude']
    $response["coordinates"][1]['longitude']
Hope it is clear now.

Comment: sorry I am new to stackoverflow can't get hold of the formatting yet :)

Comment: @ThinkDifferent Put your code in between backticks. (The ones next to the 1) Like this: `$response["coordinates"][]['latitude']`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent No worries, just a tip though, the **help** button is there for a reason, it contains the comment 'mini-Markdown' formatting.

Comment: Also, for future reference, explain what your code does in your answer. It's much easier to read for one thing.